# How I can add Multiple values from texboxes with the same name?

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to find a solution to add multiple values in my database using the same name of textboxes but I cant. I dont know exactly if there is and solution
Please see the below code.

```
<form action="" method="post">
                        <?php
                        if(isset($_POST['pats'])){
                            $pats = $_POST['pats'];
                            mysql_query("INSERT INTO trainings(pats) VALUES ('$pats')") or die(mysql_error());
                        }
                        ?>
                        <input type="text" name="pats" placeholder="Pats">
                        <input type="text" name="pats" placeholder="Pats">
                        <input type="text" name="pats" placeholder="Pats">
                        <input type="text" name="pats" placeholder="Pats">
                        <input type="text" name="pats" placeholder="Pats">
                        <input type="submit" name="insert" value="Add">
                </form>
```

Comment: Use <input type="text" name="pats[]" placeholder="Pats"> like this and you will get all values in an array then loop through that array and save in DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the [] to the name attribute of your input elements, they will then get send as an array to the server.

**If you want to add the values in different rows:**

In your backend you can then iterate over the array you received, check if there are actually values on the corresponding key and insert it into your database.

I added mysql_real_escape_string(), but you should not use this code, as it is still vulnerable to sql injections. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/3595565

```
<form action="" method="post">
        <?php
        if(isset($_POST['pats'])){
            foreach ($_POST['pats'] as $pats) {
                if(!empty($pats)){
                    mysql_query("INSERT INTO trainings(pats) VALUES ('" . mysql_real_escape_string($pats) . "')") or die(mysql_error());
                }
            }
        }
        ?>
        <input type="text" name="pats[]" placeholder="Pats">
        <input type="text" name="pats[]" placeholder="Pats">
        <input type="text" name="pats[]" placeholder="Pats">
        <input type="text" name="pats[]" placeholder="Pats">
        <input type="text" name="pats[]" placeholder="Pats">
        <input type="submit" name="insert" value="Add">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

```
<form action="" method="post">
     <?php
       if(isset($_POST['pats'])){
         foreach($_POST['pats'] as $pat) {
           mysql_query("INSERT INTO trainings(pats) VALUES ('$pat')") or die(mysql_error());
         }

       }
     ?>
                    <input type="text" name="pats[]" placeholder="Pats">
                    <input type="text" name="pats[]" placeholder="Pats">
                    <input type="text" name="pats[]" placeholder="Pats">
                    <input type="text" name="pats[]" placeholder="Pats">
                    <input type="text" name="pats[]" placeholder="Pats">
                    <input type="submit" name="insert" value="Add">
            </form>
```

It will save each value from the input as a separate row in the db.

Comment: Because you are assuming he wants the data as comma separated string. Add the solution for distinct inserts as alternative and the answer will be fine.

Comment: I think it's a fair assumption, to save multiple values in a single field in the db. How else is he supposed to achieve that?

Answer (score -1):

Use your input element name as like

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="pats[]" placeholder="Pats">
<input type="text" name="pats[]" placeholder="Pats">
<input type="text" name="pats[]" placeholder="Pats">
<input type="text" name="pats[]" placeholder="Pats">
<input type="text" name="pats[]" placeholder="Pats">
<input type="submit" name="insert" value="Add"> 
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

In your html you can pass in an array for the name..

```
<input type="text" name="pats[]" placeholder="Pats">
<input type="text" name="pats[]" placeholder="Pats">
<input type="text" name="pats[]" placeholder="Pats">
<input type="text" name="pats[]" placeholder="Pats">
```

Note the [] in the name, these are called HTML input arrays..This way php will receive an array of pats..

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['pats'])) {
        implode(',',$pats = $_POST['pats']);
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO trainings(pats) VALUES ('$pats')") or die(mysql_error());
    }
?>
```

You could use the `implode()` function to convert an array into a single string with a delimiter

Comment: Can you add the solution for inserting the values into different rows?